# c++ if else statement won't go right pathway for text adventure game, always goes to the same Void Function

Tags: c++, if-statement, void

I have c++ issues.
On a text adventure game I am making, and on a part where I have choices for different options on what to do in a house, every choice I make always goes to the void Sleep() function:

```
void Home()
{
    cout << "\nYou are in the living room of your rented home. Everything looks nice and tidy." << endl;
    cout << "Choices:" << endl;
    cout << "Sleep" << endl;
    cout << "Leave" << endl;
    cout << "Stats" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == "Sleep" || "sleep")
    {
        Sleep(); // No matter what choice I make, it always
        //goes to the Sleep(); void.
    }
    if (choice == "Leave" || choice == "leave"){
        TownSquare();
    } if (choice == "Stats" || choice == "stats") {
        StatsH();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Please choose correctly!" << endl;
        Home();
    }
}
```

All help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `if (choice == "Sleep" || "sleep")` - this line doesn't look like the others. Maybe it's not right?

Comment: why did you not use the format:  if (choice == "Leave" || choice == "leave")     for all of your decisions/branching statements??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line:

```
if (choice == "Sleep" || "sleep")
```

Evaluates as:

```
if ((choice == "Sleep") || "sleep")
```

Which is always true since `"sleep"` will always trigger. You may want to make a proper look-up table here and force the input as lower-case if that's a concern.